# Why is scrollview hiding buttons behind other views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I have a bunch of buttons in a scrollview and then below the scrollview is a horizontal linear layout with some buttons for controls and then below that is an Ad Mob banner ad.  I can't seem to figure out why when I scroll to the bottom of the list of buttons, approximately half of the last row of buttons are hidden behind the controls and banner ad.  Can anybody tell me how to make it scroll to show the full bottom row of buttons so they aren't hidden behind the linear layout for the controls and the ad banner?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 1"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 2"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 3"

                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 4"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:text=" Button 5"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 6"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:text=" Button 7"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 8"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:text=" Button 9"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button10"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 10"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:text=" Button 11"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button12"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 12"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:text=" Button 13"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button14"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button11" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Button 14"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button12" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="87dp" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlslayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Play/Pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Timer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/volume"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Volume" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The bottom row of buttons should be fully visible when scrolled down and not hidden behind the other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` in your `ScrollView` needs to be `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/controlslayout"`. Currently, your list is filling the entire screen, and the buttons are drawn over it.

Also, there isn't much point using `ConstraintLayout` if you're going to nest ViewGroups like this.

Comment: I attempted that thinking the same thing and it results in the scroll view disappearing as seen in this screenshot:  https://photos.app.goo.gl/WcQjqFsB4c8xLjrw6

Comment: Yes, that's because of how you have your constraints set up...replace `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"` with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` in your ad view.

Comment: I upvoted but since I have less than 15 reputation it says its not shown publicly but still counted.  I'm not sure how to accept it though.  This is my first time posting on here so I'm still trying to figure all of this out.